# How to specify the target directory for a AOT compiled numba extension?

Tags: python, setup.py, numba, distutils, python-packaging

I am trying to create a few AOT compiled python code for a project using `numba`.

I would like to have all my source code in a particular directory and then use these to build the compiled code through the conventional `setup.py` in a different directory. For example, let's assume my project is structured as follows

```
- numba_project/
    - numba_project/
        - __init__.py
        - src/
            - numba_source.py
        - lib/
    - setup.py
```

The `numba_source.py` looks something like

```
from numba.pycc import CC

cc = CC('my_module')

@cc.export('mul_f', 'f8(f8, f8)')
def mul(a, b):

    return a*b

cc.compile()
```

and the `setup.py` looks something like this

```
import setuptools
from numpy.distutils.core import setup
from numba_project.src.numba_source import cc

setup(
        name = 'my_numba_examples',
        # other setup arguments,
        ext_modules = [cc.distutils_extension()]
     )
```

Now, when i build extension modules through the `build_ext` command, my extension module is built into the `src/` folder. i.e.,

```
- numba_project/
    - numba_project/
        - __init__.py
        - src/
            - numba_source.py
            - my_module.so
        - lib/
    - setup.py
```

But, I would like to build the extension into the `lib/` folder. According to the [reference manual](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/reference/aot-compilation.html), the `numba` AOT compiler provides the option to specify the output directory name and file name where the extension would be built, through the `CC` instance attributes `output_dir` and `output_file` respectively. But this works only if I compile the code myself by calling the `CC` function `compile()`. When the code is compiled by the `setup.py`, the `output_dir` and `output_file` attributes are to be ignored.

So, I currently am not able to specify the target directory for my extension. I tried the Python dotted name (which is the standard while creating a C or a Fortran extension as explained [here](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/apiref.html#distutils.core.Extension)) while naming the module, i.e., something like

```
cc = CC('numba_project.lib.my_module')
```

but I get the following error

```
ValueError: basename should be a simple module name, not qualified name
```

Any suggestions on how to build the module under a target directory when building the sources from `setup.py` would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This one was a little tricky to figure out (like most AOT functions of Numba).  This is all via the command line (or put it in your AOT source file), which will compile just fine.  If you don't put an output_dir in it will make it in the current location when you use `cc.compile()`

So first you should create a cc instance like:

```
from numba .pycc import CC
cc = CC('my_module') # name your module
cc.output_dir = 'C://Username//My_Name//my_output_dir//' # set the output directory
```

All the CC flags are passed this way for AOT compiling.  You can just type this in a terminal before you finally do a:

```
cc.compile()
```

And yes I confimed that's where the output PYD goes.  You could also put it in your script under a: `if __name__ == "__main__":` block with `cc.compile()` if you want to run the script and it will compile at the same time.